# Lucene.NET Lock obtain timed out error

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, lucene, lucene.net

I'm getting the following error when running a process that updates a Lucene index with some User data (a domain object).

> Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out:
>   AzureLock@write.lock. at Lucene.Net.Store.Lock.Obtain(Int64
>   lockWaitTimeout) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Store\Lock.cs: line 97 at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Init(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean
>   create, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, Int32 maxFieldLength,
>   IndexingChain indexingChain, IndexCommit commit) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Index\IndexWriter.cs: line 1228
>   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter..ctor(Directory d, Analyzer a,
>   MaxFieldLength mfl) in
>   d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Index\IndexWriter.cs: line 174
>   at
>   MyApp.ApplicationServices.Search.Users.UsersSearchEngineService.EnsureIndexWriter()
>   at 
>   MyApp.ApplicationServices.Search.Users.UsersSearchEngineService.DoWriterAction(Action`1
>   action) at....

I've inherited the following code and my knowledge of Lucene is not great, so any pointers would be appreciated.

```
public class UsersSearchEngineService : IUsersSearchEngineService
{

   private readonly Directory directory;
   private readonly Analyzer analyzer;
   private static IndexWriter indexWriter;
   private static readonly Object WriterLock = new Object();
   private bool disposed;

   public UsersSearchEngineService (ILuceneDirectoryProvider directoryProvider)
    {
        directory = directoryProvider.GetDirectory();
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
    }

    public int UpdateIndex(IEnumerable<User> itemsToIndex)
    {
        var updatedCount = 0;

        foreach (var itemToIndex in itemsToIndex)
        {
            try
            {
                ExecuteRemoveItem(itemToIndex.UserId);

                var document = CreateIndexDocument(itemToIndex);

                DoWriterAction(writer => writer.AddDocument(document));


                updatedCount++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogProvider.Error("Error updating index for User with id:[{0}]", ex, itemToIndex.UserId);
            }
        }

        DoWriterAction(writer =>
        {
            writer.Commit();
            writer.Optimize();
        });

        return updatedCount;
    }

     private static Document CreateIndexDocument(User itemToIndex)
    {
        var document = new Document();

        document.Add(new Field("id", itemToIndex.UserId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        //...
        //omitted other fields being added here 
        //...

        return document;
    }

    void ExecuteRemoveItem(int entryId)
    {
        var searchQuery = GetIdSearchQuery(entryId);
        DoWriterAction(writer => writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery));

    }

    void DoWriterAction(Action<IndexWriter> action)
        {
            lock (WriterLock)
            {
                EnsureIndexWriter();
            }
            action(indexWriter);
        }


  void EnsureIndexWriter()
    {
        if (indexWriter != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(this.directory, this.analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        indexWriter.SetMergePolicy(new LogDocMergePolicy(indexWriter) { MergeFactor = 5 });

        var retryStrategy = new ExponentialBackoff(5, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<LuceneWriterLockedErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

        retryPolicy.Retrying += (sender, args) => EventLogProvider.Warn("Retrying lock delete Attempt: " + args.CurrentRetryCount);

        if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(this.directory))
        {
            retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
            {
                EventLogProvider.Info("Something left a lock in the index folder: Attempting to it");
                IndexWriter.Unlock(directory);
                EventLogProvider.Info("Lock Deleted... can proceed");
            });
        }

    }

    ~UsersSearchEngineService ()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (WriterLock)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                var writer = indexWriter;

                if (writer != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
                    {
                        EventLogProvider.Error("Exception while disposing SearchEngineService", e);
                    }
                    indexWriter = null;
                }

                var disposeDirectory = directory;
                if (disposeDirectory != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        disposeDirectory.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
                    {
                        EventLogProvider.Error("Exception while disposing SearchEngineService", e);
                    }
                }

                disposed = true;
            }
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

}

In case it's relevant:

- the application is hosted as an Azure Web App, running 2 instances
- the index is stored in Azure Storage
- the procedure runs as a       scheduled process defined in a CMS.
- The CMS will only launch allow  one    instance of scheduled process to be running at any
  one time in a load balanced    scenario (e.g. when running 2
  instances in Azure)

Does the EnsureIndexWriter method look correct? If not, how should it be reworked?

Comment: Is UsersSearchEngineService a transient object? Meaning, is it shortlived only during the time of indexation? Since you only release the writelock during Dispose of that class, it will be alive as long as that Service is alive, which seems wrong to me. The writer should be disposed after the commit/optimize phase, preferably, to make it accessible to other threads and processes (and instances).

Comment: I would also suggest running all AddDocument calls within the same scope, followed by a Commit/Optimize and ensure that it is the same writer. Right not it tries to EnsureWriter before each add and then before the Optimize/Commit. This will work if you will be certain that it is the same writer, but you also have some retry logic there that indicates that it might have lost the writer somewhere, which shouldn't happen. You should consider an index update as one transaction.